# Missing launchfile after exporting E(fx)clipse RCP product application

Tags: export, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm trying to export a Eclipse FX application as an product. So far I did the tutorial from [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial3) to create an example application. The application can be started via the **Launch an Eclipse application** button which shows up in the product file editor. When the applicaion is lanuched it works as supposed.

[image]

The problem now is the export as a product. When I hit the **Eclipse Product export wizard** another dialogue opens which asks me for the location for storing the product export. Afterwards I hit the **Finish** button and the export completes without any warnings. The result is a **eclipse** folder which contains some files and folders (which look correct so far) but there is no executable / launch file.

[image]

I have no clue what is going wrong here. I also tried the delta package (the one released especially for the eclipse version. I downloaded both the Eclipse an the delta package from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/M-4.4.1RC1-201408130800/) to avoid incompatibilities.

Im using

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Eclipse SDK Luna SR1 (4.4.1) Bild id: M20140813-0800
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)

I'm thankful for any help :-)

Comment: Eclipse 4.4.1 is still only a Release Candidate so might still have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution the stated problem. It is unfortuneatley not intuitive. You need to add the eclipse installation directory to the target platform and afterwards to the 'pom.xml' in your product folder. Now I describe the solution step by step. Go to 'Preference > Plug-in development' select the JavaFX target platform and edit it. In the Tab 'Locations' you select 'Add... > Directory > next' and select the root folder of you eclipse installation. In my case it was '~/eclipse'. After a 'Project > Clean ... > clean all projects' and the export works perfectly.